# Reading until end of line

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read from a file in C as a part of a project of mine.

My PURPOSE is to parse the words in that file(which are either separated by a whitespace, comma, semicolon or the new line character) into tokens.

For that I **MUST** read character by character.

```
do {

    do {

        tempChar = fgetc(asmCode);
        strcpy(&tempToken[i], &tempChar);

        i++;

    } while (tempChar != ' ' || tempChar != ':' || tempChar != ';' || tempChar != ',' || tempChar != '\n');//reading until the given parameters

    i = 0;

    //some other code with some other purpose

} while (tempChar != EOF);//reading until the end of the file
```

Even though the following code reads from the file, it doesn't stop reading since somehow it doesn't apply the conditions inside while.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. both tempChar & tempToken are defined as char variables. also another

Comment: `strcpy(&tempToken[i], &tempChar);` <- `strcpy` expects a 0-terminated `char` array as source, you're passing the address of one `char` with who-knows-what following in memory.

Comment: You inner loop has no test for escaping if you reach EOF, and you should use && instead of || to do what you want. Also, tempToken[i] = tempChar, not strcpy, as per above commenter.

Comment: Did you mean `&&` instead of `||`, btw?

Comment: Hello, Why don't you read the complete file and store it in a string and then use strtok? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: The return type of [`fgetc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: I can't use strtok since i've to read character by character from the file. Also it must be ||.

Comment: fwiw, a newline *is* whitespace, so you're covered by just that.

Comment: No, it's definitely not ||. What if tempChar is a semicolon? Then the first test will return 1 (a semicolon is not a space), but since you're using an OR, 1 OR 0 = 1, so (because of [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) the rest of the tests will not even be evaluated. You definitely want &&.

Comment: && would make tempChar be all of those at the same time. tempChar keeps changing as the loop goes along. It's either one at a time.

Comment: @Dubslow I got your answer now after reading a20365354's detailed answer. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something is going wrong with this line of code:

`while (tempChar != ' ' || tempChar != ':' || tempChar != ';' || tempChar != ',' || tempChar != '\n');`

Since you used ||, the condition is always true, making it an infinity loop.
Try this, this may work:

`while (tempChar != ' ' && tempChar != ':' && tempChar != ';' && tempChar != ',' && tempChar != '\n');`

Also, I prefer `if(feof(asmCode))` over `if (tempChar == EOF)`. In case the the value tempChar is same as EOF, `if (tempChar == EOF)` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

as I see in your code the type of `tempchar` is char: `char tempchar`

you can not use `strcpy(&tempToken[i], &tempChar);` to copy char. the strcpy copy string to a sting buffer.

try the following fixed code

```
do {

    do {

        tempChar = fgetc(asmCode);

        if (tempChar == EOF)
            break;
        tempToken[i]= tempChar;

        i++;

    } while (tempChar != ' ' || tempChar != ':' || tempChar != ';' || tempChar != ',' || tempChar != '\n');//reading until the given parameters
    tempToken[i]='0';
    i = 0;  // this will erase the old content of tempToken !!! what are you trying to do here ?

    //some other code with some other purpose

} while (tempChar != EOF);//reading until the end of the file
```

Comment: with some additional changes to your code, I made it work. Thanks a lot for that. But this time I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for tempToken[i] = tempChar; since checking for EOF doesn't work I suspect.